# How to scan QR in webform vb.net

Tags: vb.net, qr-code

I want to do QR Scanner in **webform VB.NET**. I want to do like this press a button to open the camera then scan the QR Code. I found one package call **QRCoder** can generate the QR Code. My problem is I did not find the way to decode the QR. Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try ZXing .Net. I think it has a Nuget package

Answer (score 0):

You need to scan the QRCode in your front-end, not the back-end. You can use  [this library](https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode) to scan a QR Code and send to your back-end.